How to solve problems after installing Windows 10 in Virtiual Manager with GPU passthrough?
I managed to pass GPU to virtual machine using this tutorial . I installed Windows 10 but not everything works properly.

I see my GTX 1050 Ti in Device Manager along with Microsoft Basic Adapter. Is that how it's supposed to be? I saw in different tutorials that Basic Adapter was absent there and only passed through GPU was present.



I can't change resolution. It's locked at 1280 x 700. Also when I go to Advanced display settings it says the display is connected to Microsoft Basic Adapter instead of to GTX 1050 Ti.



I installed VIRTIO drivers from here but that disabled mouse in my Virtual Machine. I could change resolution though. I unsinstalled those drivers, that brought mouse back but can't change resolution again. I reinstalled the guest system and installed Virtio drivers again. It works without an issue now.

I'm super new to this, I started not even 12 hours ago and I'm not sure how to troubleshoot it or what information to provide to make everything clearer, so be patient with me please.
Thanks.

You passed-through your display card, but it sounds like you are somehow expecting it to be used for a virtual display (i.e., some window on a host) instead of a physical one connected to the card? GPU (PCIe) passthrough is not the same things as virtio-gpu. For the former you can disable the "basic adapter" with -vga none (or -nodefaults).

@TomYan Thanks for sparing some time to reply to my post, I appreciate it. "but it sounds like you are somehow expecting it to be used for a virtual display" - that's exactly what I'm expecting but I assume that's not possible? Can I use my VM direcly connecting monitor cable to the card and using only GPU which has been passed through completely omiting Basic Adapter? I'm not sure where to use -vga none or -nodefaults. I'm using Virtual Manager to manage my VMs.
